# PHP form but for some reason It doesn't recognize the last text area

Tags: php, html

Right now I am trying to figure out what is going on with the code. It doesn't make sense why it won't work. When I submit the form I get the error message "comments two" so I know where the problem is but don't understand why its happening. The $newfield variable I made seems to not be storing anything. Any help?

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="contact-formular">

            <div id="message"></div>

            <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

            <div class="one_half element_from_left" style="opacity: 1; left: 0px;">            
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name'; }" value="Name">
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'email'; }" value="email">                
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'phone') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'phone'; }" value="phone">            
            </div>

            <div class="one_half last element_from_right" style="opacity: 1; right: 0px;">      

                <textarea id="comments" type="text" class="top-text" name="comments" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="comments">Architect/ lighting designer/ property developer/ lighting enthusiast/ Will tell later</textarea>

                <textarea id="newfield" type="text" class="bottom-text" name="newfield"  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="newfield">Newfield</textarea>             

            </div>            

                <input type="submit" class="send_message" id="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">

            </form>

        </div>
```

PHP CODE:

```
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$newfield = $_POST['newfield'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];


if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Comments one</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($newfield) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Comments two</div>';
    exit();
}
```

Also here is a picture of what it looks like for the error when I submit. If I remove this line of code it works but doesn't capture that area for an email:

```
else if(trim($newfield) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Comments two</div>';
        exit();
    }
```

here is also the full php document https://codeshare.io/GAW7x5

Comment: remove the attribute `value=""` from the textareas.

Comment: Why are you using type="text"  inside of textarea? Type will be used in input fields.

Comment: This code is  run without any error for me... your code is correct.. not getting any error...

Comment: @WEBjuju I removed the value="" from the text areas and still the same error.

Comment: @pravinvavadiya is right, the textareas are producing POST vars just fine (regardless of all the invalid html...i just figured you must be using some browser that is choking on the invalid html).

Comment: @PravinVavadiya not sure if this helps but here is the full php document https://codeshare.io/GAW7x5 it is a bit odd to me that the form won't submit..and it gives me the error "comments two" on submission.

Comment: I checked this with your full php code and i getting "Email Sent Successfully."  this without any error...